# Groovy script does not write file as UTF-8

Tags: groovy, utf-8, file-writing

I have the following piece of code:

```
def f = new File("test.txt")
f.write("test", "UTF-8")
```

When opening the file in Notepad++ (or any other editor) it is still in ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8. Opening the file in a hex editor it does not contain the "magic bytes" `0xEFBBBF`.

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 files [do not really require the Byte-Order Mark indicator](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#BOM).

For example, if your UTF-8 file only contains ASCII chars, the `file` utility will return this:

```
$ file [filename]
ASCII text
```

But when you introduce, say, Japanese chars into that file, then `file` will return this:

```
UTF-8 Unicode text
```

.. but the file will not begin with the BOM.

Comment: +1 - Also, the BOM has been known to break plenty of programs that don't expect it!

Answer (score 0):

Remember, Groovy is based on Java.  Just write:

```
File outFile = new File(filePath)
Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream(outFile), "UTF8"));
out.append(strBuf.toString())
out.flush()
out.close()
```